# Where is a function array parameter stored between subsequent calls in Python?

Tags: python, scope

I am wanting to understand how Python maintains its reference to the array value between the first call and second call to the function. Is there a symbolic table that can be queried or looked at to see what the object values are between the first and second call.

```
def scopeUnderstanding2(a, myArray=[]):
    print(f"myArray in func scopeUnderstanding2 myArray : {myArray}")
    myArray.append(a)
    print(f"myArray in func after .append(a) myArray : {myArray}")

print (scopeUnderstanding2(1)) 
print (scopeUnderstanding2(2)) 

myArray in func scopeUnderstanding2 myArray : []
myArray in func after .append(a) myArray : [1]
None
myArray in func scopeUnderstanding2 myArray : [1]
myArray in func after .append(a) myArray : [1, 2]
None
```

Comment: The default parameter values, which were evaluated at the time the function was defined, are kept in the `__defaults__` attribute of the function itself (`func_defaults` in older versions).  Note that it's generally considered a mistake to use a mutable value as a default, as the results can be quite unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Any default parameters that you define in the function's `def` statement are stored as part of the resulting function object in an attribute called `__defaults__`:

```
>>> def scopeUnderstanding2(a, myArray=[]):
...     print(f"myArray in func scopeUnderstanding2 myArray : {myArray}")
...     myArray.append(a)
...     print(f"myArray in func after .append(a) myArray : {myArray}")
...
>>> dir(scopeUnderstanding2)
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> scopeUnderstanding2.__defaults__
([],)
>>> scopeUnderstanding2(1)
myArray in func scopeUnderstanding2 myArray : []
myArray in func after .append(a) myArray : [1]
>>> scopeUnderstanding2.__defaults__
([1],)
```

If `myArray` had been declared as a *local* variable inside the *body* of the function, it would be re-created each time the function is called, rather than associated permanently with the function object itself.

Comment: It might be important adding there that most uses of mutable objects as default parameters are made by people _unaware_ that the same object will be used across calls, and it is one of the major "gotchas" in Python.

Comment: And to your point in the last paragraph - that's why we have the idiom of making the default parameter `myArray=None`, and then at the start of the function doing `myArray = myArray or []` or similar.

Comment: OP's question strongly implies to me that they're already aware of how it works, and are just curious about where exactly the default parameter lives and how to peek at it.  :)  But anyone who's actually being bitten by this behavior or trying to understand *why* it works this way should check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument